# Pivot table value display

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to change the way a pivot table displays values that im trying to track on a month to month basis.  Below is a picture of what I have vs what I would like:

[image]

The first table is what I have.  The second table is one I manually created to show what I would like displayed.  Basically what I want to display is the % of total in column P for all of the highlighted cells in column F through O.  I cant figure this one out after a good bit of trial and error and googling.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an additional picture to add clarity to what I'm trying to display:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what the percentages relate to in your screenshot.

In a pivot table you can set the values to display as percentages, with a few different options, like percentage of total, percentage of column, percentage of row, etc.

This [Microsoft Support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-different-calculations-in-PivotTable-value-fields-014d2777-baaf-480b-a32b-98431f48bfec) has the details how to set it up.

Comment: I added a second picture for clarity.  I've tried the things you mentioned with no success